# Using std::string's std::hash specialization without constructing a string object

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a codebase which makes extensive use of CUDA, which unfortunately only supports C++14 to date. However, I still want to use string_view, which is a C++17 feature. The implementation is relatively straight-forward, especially since I do not require the 'find' functionalities.

However, I do need hashing to work. The standard mandates that std::hash of a string_view must be the equal to the hash of a string constructed from the string_view (and I intend to rely on this guarantee). Is there a standard-conform way of getting the output from std::hash without having to temporarily construct a string object, which may come with an unoptimizable heap allocation (which is the route that [string-view-lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/string-view-lite) went)? I would rather not rely on copying over the algorithm from the concrete stdlib implementation, since that might break in the future or already breaks compilation with older versions.

Alternatively, is there a way to let MSVC (EDIT: v14.16) use std::string_view in C++14-mode, which NVCC also recognizes? It would be great if Clang and GCC had a similar option as well, since the codebase might migrate away from MSVC one day.

Comment: Why don't you use a custom hashing function everywhere instead?

Comment: @Acorn I realize this might be the only viable option, but "everywhere" is in quite a few places and surely more error-prone than specializing std::hash once - if such a thing is possible

Comment: What's wrong with using [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/) [gsl::string_span](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/string_span) ? I'm 90% sure it supports your MSVC version - after all, the common implementation is Microsoft's.

Comment: @einpoklum Because it suffers the same problem that copying over the implementation of the stdlib's hashing has: should MSVC's implementation change the algorithm, it would lead to subtle bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are out of luck in my opinion since, also by assuming that you could mimic the internal structure and pass a tailored object to fulfill and look like a `std::string`, that would surely be more fragile than just copying the implementation.

I see two choices, either:

- you copy the `std::hash<std::string>` specialization implementation and put some asserts with hardcoded cases which may warn you if anything changes or is different (rather a clumsy solution).
- you provide your own hash function which overrides `std::string` one and pass it as template argument so that you can enforce the constraint of them being equal when working with STL collections.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. To you happen to know if Is it allowed by the standard to replace the `std::hash<std::string>>` specialization with my own hash function, which will then also be used by my custom `string_view`?

Comment: The specializations are just there to be used with `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map` as default template argument, there's no "standard" way to hash a string, it's just that a default hasher is provided, you are free to supply your own function, a simple type alias could change this project-wide.

Comment: Ah, I was foolishly thinking about somehow "overriding" the template specialization with something else, a feat not quite possible in C++ I'm afraid. I guess I'll indeed have to provide a custom hash functor.